# convert epoch to readable data time in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which one of the column is in epoch time:

```
df1['timestamp']
```

is something like this:

```
1533009600000
1533013200000  
1533016800000 



timestamp    object
```

I need to convert to human readable time stamp. I tried this:

```
import time
df1['timestamp']=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(df1['timestamp']))
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>
```

what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: @Prune, I am following the datetime conversion, but I am getting some weird error. It is really not the same type of question.

Comment: My apologies; thanks for the extra focus.  The problem is in the Pandas handling.  The original column is of type `float`, and you're changing that on the fly.  You need the proper astype() conversion to do this.

Comment: what is the unit of the timestamp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert based on the unit of the epoch time. The number is too large for s, assuming it is ms

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit = 'ms')


    timestamp
0   2018-07-31 04:00:00
1   2018-07-31 05:00:00
2   2018-07-31 06:00:00
```